# Correct way to pass table-valued function outputs to table-valued functions in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a user-defined in-line table-valued function in SQL Server 2008 called "imageFileFromAddress":

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].imageFileFromAddress (@address NVARCHAR(max))
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN(
--Guts of the function.
);
```

The guts of the return are intended to be this, from a logical standpoint:

```
WITH addresses AS 
(
      SELECT * FROM [dbo].[bookPageFromAddress](@address)
)
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[imageFileFromBookPage](addresses.Book, addresses.Page)
```

So, bookPageFromAddress and imageFileFromBookPage are also user-defined in-line table-valued functions; I need to pass the address parameter to the former, which produces a table as output, and use its rows as arguments to the latter, taking the tables it produces, stitching them together into a single table, and returning the result.  Obviously the actual code above is not valid for that, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the proper syntax.  What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Both `imageFileFromAddress()` and `bookPageFromAddress()` taking same `@address` parameter, why do you need `imageFileFromAddress()` function?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  [dbo].bookPageFromAddress(@address) addresses
  outer apply [dbo].[imageFileFromBookPage](addresses.Book, addresses.Page) foo
```

Comment: Thanks!  This didn't work, but it seems like a promising line of inquiry, and I really appreciate being pointed in the right direction.